# Line Break not Appearing in Vim

Tags: vim, text

Please consider the following problem. [Using this text file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4619870/output4.txt), I am trying to set it up so it is a tab-deliminated file. It should look like this, as it does in vim:

[image]

Note that there is the 1, followed by a tab (^I, appearing in light blue above), and then the text of the website.

But when I open the very same file in TextEdit, I get this:

[image]

Where is the spurious line break coming from? I can't find it in vim.

Comment: Is there any reason you're concerned with the way TextEdit renders the content of the file?

Comment: @jahroy I'm feeding it into another program, which is breaking because it is interpreting a line break in there somehow. If I manually remove the line break in TextEdit, the other program works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If  you place  your  cursor on  the  space right  after the  URL  and use  the
[`ga`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#ga) command, you'll  notice that it's actually a  unicode line separator
(its hex code will show as 2028).

So probably  what's happening is  that Vim render it  as a regular  space, but
other editors  as a  line break.  Just replace that  character with  a regular
space and it will solve this.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. On the off hand that you know at hand, do you know how to remove these w/ bash?

Comment: @ian.milligan Well, you can use sed. The sequence for that character in UTF-8 is `E280A8` (see [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm)). So the command `sed -i.old $'s/\xE2\x80\xA8/ /g' filename` will replace those characters with a regular space, and leave the old file backup'ed with the same name plus the extension ".old". I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command

```
:set nocompatible
```

If that works put it into your vimrc file.